# Using IPython/Jupyter cluster with R kernel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, ipython, jupyter

I would like to use IPython/Jupyter to set up 100 jobs on a computing cluster to perform some calculations.

In Python, I would do the following

```
from IPython.parallel import Client
c = Client()
c[:].apply_sync(lambda : "Hello, World")
```

Or, using ipython-cluster-helper

```
with cluster_view(scheduler="lsf", queue="myqueue", num_jobs=100) as view:
    result = view.map(myfunc, params)
```

Is it possible to access IPython's parallel abilities from an R kernel?

If yes, how?

There are some parallel processing capabilities in R, but this would need to be a function provided by the IRkernel.

I would expect that if I run the line below (with a corresponding function to access the IPython/Jupyter cluster), I would see parallel execution times:

```
parallel_access_func(1:4, function(x) { re = as.character(Sys.time()); Sys.sleep(5); re })
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but the R Kernel would need to be re-implemented using  [MetaKernel](https://github.com/Calysto/metakernel/blob/master/README.rst). MetaKernel allows any MetaKernel-based kernel to be run in parallel, using the [%parallel and %px magics](https://github.com/Calysto/metakernel/blob/master/metakernel/magics/README.md#parallel). It might not be too difficult to reimplement.

Comment: Looking at MetaKernel, this could be reasonably straightforward. How difficult would it be to make use of this from a command-line R session? I must say, I'm eyeing just using rzmq directly to do my parallel computing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible like you imagine it: `ipyparallel` is a **Python** parallel execution lib with Jupyter `ipykernel`s as backend. It can be more or less used independently from the notebook/IPython.

To make this work with an R kernel, you would need to implement a `irparallel` library which would do the same with the `irkernel`, e.g. at least a function which interacts with a controller and R engines which start `irkernels` instead of `ipykernels`. All of this does not exist (yet--but nor is it planned).

There are other R parallel libs (as there are other Python parallel libs), which might do what you want (I don't have any experience with them). Have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html